# Iframe Problems with the Li element

Tags: html, css, iframe

I just got an Problem with an iframe and an other element:

**CSS:**

```
body
{
    margin-right: 0px;
}

ul 
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
    min-width: 750px;
    max-width: auto;
    border-top-left-radius: 35%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 35%;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
}

li 
{
    float: left;
}

li a
{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover 
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

iframe
{
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li class="leftcorn"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Kontakt</a></li>
  <li class="rightcorn"><a href="#about">Über uns</a></li>
</ul>
<iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
```

[image: This is the Website]

I can't press the Button, maybe the li over the iframe is in way 
but how i fix it that it will work?

I just tried everything and I´m not so good, it´s just an Hobbie for me. :)

Comment: can you post the iframe code please?

Answer (score 0):

iframes need direct urls to gather contents in order to be able for other people can see. src="iframe.html" will not help your case, they reference local index.html, it will work on your machine, but it will not for us to help? we can help if the iframe exists on a server ie http:// otherwise we cant see what you are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you have z-index:-1; remove this and see if it works

Comment: yes it will be work i know but then it will overlay the display with the home and co.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

```
    z-index: -1;
```

for the iframe it will not be clickable as the main body z-index would be greater hence not allowing the click functionality. Think of it as a stack the higher the z-index of the item it would be on top. It is a good practice to give z-index to iframe that is more than the z-index of the body. If they are conditionally rendered.